# How ADT Names dexedLibs Folder jar Files

Tags: android, adt

as `dexedLibs` introduced in ADT 21 to prevent redexing the jar files over and over, I would like to learn how does ADT names the JAR file after dexing them for example:

before:

```
 android-support-v4.jar
```

after

```
 android-support-v4-bc2c2eef0f5f5f5b0ad0410bfc67acf4.jar
```

ADT added a postfix `-bc2c2eef0f5f5f5b0ad0410bfc67acf4` to the jar file it looks like a hash or something, could any body tell what is the mechanism ADT use to rename the jar file?

any help or guide would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This happen in `BuildHelper.java` in the ADT check function `executeDx`

you can find it online

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/sdk/+/49abd0e6285b6397969e4e9a5ce83f02c6e53422/eclipse/plugins/com.android.ide.eclipse.adt/src/com/android/ide/eclipse/adt/internal/build/BuildHelper.java